# How to upload csv file in elasticsearch using logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-5, logstash-configuration, kibana-6

this is my logstash.conf file data

```
   input {
  file {
    path => "/home/niteshb/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}                

filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["tenant_id","hierarchy_name","attribute_name","item_pk"]
  }
}                

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts  => "http://localhost:9200"
    index  => "plan_record"
  }
  stdout {}
}
```

and to run it I am using

```
bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

After running it runs into exception and the exception  is

```
  ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [A-Za-z0-9_-], [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"=>\" at line 9, column 6 (byte 138) after input {\n  file {\n    path => \"/home/niteshb/*.csv\"\n    start_position => \"beginning\"\n    sincedb_path => \"dev/NULL\"\n  }\n\n  filter {\n  csv", :backtrace=>["/home/niteshb/Music/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "/home/niteshb/Music/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in `initialize'", "/home/niteshb/Music/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "/home/niteshb/Music/logstash-7.12.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:389:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2021-04-26T18:15:40,601][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-04-26T18:15:40,611][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
```

can someone please help me with this issue I am using linux system and I dont know whats going wrong ?

Comment: Where are you storing the ```logstash.conf``` config file? Are you keeping it ```/etc/logstash/conf.d/``` ?

Comment: if the location of the config file is correct, then probably it is the issue related to the formatting of the config file. Please convert it into proper format.

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to properly format your configuration files. You're simply missing an closing curly brace at the end of the `input` and `filter` sections:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/niteshb/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}                  <--- add this

filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["tenant_id","hierarchy_name","attribute_name","item_pk"]
  }
}                  <--- add this

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts  => "http://localhost:9200"
    index  => "plan_record"
  }
  stdout {}
}
```

Comment: same issue persists , I have edited the question , with the logs pls check it

Comment: Can you paste the output you get when running `bin/logstash -t --log.level=debug -f logstash.conf` ?

Comment: It's resolved , tried something similar , I will just share may be it can help somone